# prime faces calendar not refreshing when custom validator

Tags: jquery, validation, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I've  component which has custom validator to validate for certain format(MM/dd/YYYY). When format is like 07/22/0215(wrong date), its showing validtion error. After validation error, when I get back my dialog(calendar is in dialog), its showing same wrong date, instead of current date.
Can you please help me to get refresh calendar to current date? Many Thanks.
Calendar is in panel and panel is in dialog.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I might suggest you read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better idea on how to ask a good question.  You have good detail - but I'm not sure the community has enough info to help you diagnose/solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Tiny: that is why I always, before even trying to reproduce, ask for a version. If the version is before the latest I always ask to try the latest. Saves me time chasing ghosts.